# bootstrap 3 - navbar brand responsive not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar brand image of 408px x 130. The navigation look correct in browser but i cannot make it responsive on mobile. Also the menu button does not appear.  This is my navbar

```
<nav class="navbar default-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <img alt="#{site_title}" src="/images/logo_white.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/faq">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contacts">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li></li>


                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="loginButton">Accedi</a>
                        <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <form action="/" method="post" class="form">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="username" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-username form-control" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="password" />
                                                <div class="help-block text-right">
                                                    <a href="/resetPassword"> <span class="login-link">Password dimenticata?</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label> <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="remember-me" /> <span>Ricordami</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom text-center">
                                        <span>Non sei iscritto?</span> <a class="login-link" href="/register"><strong>Registrati</strong></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>

    </nav>
```

The style is pure bootstrap css out of this

```
navbar {
    min-height: 130px;
    line-height: 130px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 130px;
}
```

which i need to fit the nav to the brand image height.

The problem is that when i use a mobile phone, the brand image does is not responsive, so the menu button does not appear and the logo gets all the screen...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marioconforti/74bokd1g/1/)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Thanks, i added it

Comment: If you change your `nav` class to `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">`, you will see your menu button. You can set the `.navbar-toggle` background color to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the nav button is still there but because the `nav` element doesn't have the `.navbar-default` class, it isn't inheriting Bootstrap's styles. You can fix this by adding the following:

**CSS**

```
.navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
    top: 37px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

You'll also need to add jQuery and Bootstrap js to enable the nav toggle for the menu

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To fix the image you'll need to do the following (styles may need adjusting based on how you need it to look)

You can set the height of `.navbar-brand` to `auto` and remove the height from `.navbar`. Also, changing its `box-sizing` to `content` will allow the image to sit within the padding of the element. You'll then need to add the `.img-responsive` class to the logo image element.

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        max-width: 15em;
    }
}

/* Optional to replace line-height centering */ 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;  /* ( .navbar height / 2 ) - ( #navbar height / 2 ) */
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Add img-responsive class to your logo -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img alt="#{site_title}" src="http://2.228.86.3:8080/images/quipark_logo_white.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's a Codepen example: https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/YrKMgg

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you